# C++ find where a function is being called from to find a vector range check error

Tags: c++, vector, debug-information

I am running into a range check error from a vector that I am having trouble pin pointing. I am working in a VERY large c++ framework that is not really very well designed. Python is used as a UI which then calls c++ functions/classes to do all the heavy lifting. So the actual command I run is 'python thing.py --option1 etc...'. There is a function that returns an object that it finds by an index in a vector. There are two vectors that it can use based on a bool that is set. To be more concrete, I have something like:

```
object getObject(int i, bool trig=false){
    if(trig) return vector1.at(i);
    return vector2.at(i);
}
```

The problem is that the vectors will be of different lengths so if you either give it the wrong index or you forget to set the 'trig' bool, there is a good chance you will go out of range. This function or something like it is called thousands of times across many different files so I am having trouble finding where this range check error is actually coming from. Currently I have been either commenting out blocks of code, or putting in print outs to try to find where the code gets before it crashes but this is proving quite difficult considering the number of places I have to do this.

Is there an easy way to print out where this function was called from when I get the range check error? Stack trace or something like that? I am not really familiar with things like this.

**Update:**
I have tried using GDB with a command like:

```
gdb -ex  r --args python fakes.py --datasets data --dir outdir
```

I see the same error I always get which looks like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "fakes.py", line 299, in <module>
main(options,args)
File "fakes.py", line 240, in main
driver.submit(job, submitDir)
Exception: void EL::Driver::submit(const EL::Job& job,
const string& location) =>
DataVector::at range check (C++ exception)
```

Then it drops me into the GDB command line. If I type bt (which seems to be the right command to get the stack trace) I get the message "No stack."

I tried running Valgrind with this command too but I am not seeing anything useful in it. I could just be missing something however since I am new to valgrind. The following is the output of valgrind around where the error appears:

```
==344722== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==344722==    at 0xE80FEC5: TObject::~TObject() (in /cvmfs/atlas.cern.ch/repo/ATLASLocalRootBase/x86_64/root/6.04.12-x86_64-slc6-gcc49-opt/lib/libCore.so)
==344722==    by 0x25437C52: EL::Driver::submitOnly(EL::Job const&, std::string const&) const (Driver.cxx:103)
==344722==    by 0x25437F88: EL::Driver::submit(EL::Job const&, std::string const&) const (Driver.cxx:84)
==344722==    by 0x1CA83031: ???
==344722==    by 0xFFE6F7E: TClingCallFunc::exec(void*, void*) const (in /cvmfs/atlas.cern.ch/repo/ATLASLocalRootBase/x86_64/root/6.04.12-x86_64-slc6-gcc49-opt/lib/libCling.so)
==344722==    by 0xD1AA1AE: PyROOT::TVoidExecutor::Execute(long, void*, PyROOT::TCallContext*) (in /cvmfs/atlas.cern.ch/repo/ATLASLocalRootBase/x86_64/root/6.04.12-x86_64-slc6-gcc49-opt/lib/libPyROOT.so)
==344722==    by 0xD1CB0CB: PyROOT::TMethodHolder::CallSafe(void*, long, PyROOT::TCallContext*) (in /cvmfs/atlas.cern.ch/repo/ATLASLocalRootBase/x86_64/root/6.04.12-x86_64-slc6-gcc49-opt/lib/libPyROOT.so)
==344722==    by 0xD1C9DB9: PyROOT::TMethodHolder::Execute(void*, long, PyROOT::TCallContext*) (in /cvmfs/atlas.cern.ch/repo/ATLASLocalRootBase/x86_64/root/6.04.12-x86_64-slc6-gcc49-opt/lib/libPyROOT.so)
==344722==    by 0xD1C8A24: PyROOT::TMethodHolder::Call(PyROOT::ObjectProxy*, _object*, _object*, PyROOT::TCallContext*) (in /cvmfs/atlas.cern.ch/repo/ATLASLocalRootBase/x86_64/root/6.04.12-x86_64-slc6-gcc49-opt/lib/libPyROOT.so)
==344722==    by 0xD1E35A4: PyROOT::(anonymous namespace)::mp_call(PyROOT::MethodProxy*, _object*, _object*) (in /cvmfs/atlas.cern.ch/repo/ATLASLocalRootBase/x86_64/root/6.04.12-x86_64-slc6-gcc49-opt/lib/libPyROOT.so)
==344722==    by 0x4C61B62: PyObject_Call (abstract.c:2529)
==344722==    by 0x4D161AD: PyEval_EvalFrameEx (ceval.c:4251)
==344722==
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fakes.py", line 299, in <module>
    main(options,args)
  File "fakes.py", line 240, in main
    driver.submit(job, submitDir)
Exception: void EL::Driver::submit(const EL::Job& job, const string& location) =>
    DataVector::at range check (C++ exception)
==344722== Invalid read of size 4
==344722==    at 0x4CB08F3: PyObject_Free (obmalloc.c:994)
==344722==    by 0x4D55452: collect (gcmodule.c:821)
==344722==    by 0x4D55D27: PyGC_Collect (gcmodule.c:1440)
==344722==    by 0x4D3E018: Py_Finalize (pythonrun.c:449)
==344722==    by 0x4D53F8E: Py_Main (main.c:665)
==344722==    by 0x3038C1ED5C: (below main) (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==344722==  Address 0x682d020 is 16 bytes before a block of size 48 alloc'd
==344722==    at 0x4A085FC: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:298)
==344722==    by 0x10B7DD41: clang::ASTReader::ReadDeclContextStorage(clang::serialization::ModuleFile&, llvm::BitstreamCursor&, std::pair<unsigned long, unsigned long> const&, clang::serialization::DeclContextInfo&) (in /cvmfs/atlas.cern.ch/repo/ATLASLocalRootBase/x86_64/root/6.04.12-x86_64-slc6-gcc49-opt/lib/libCling.so)
==344722==    by 0x10BD8CCC: clang::ASTReader::ReadDeclRecord(unsigned int) (in /cvmfs/atlas.cern.ch/repo/ATLASLocalRootBase/x86_64/root/6.04.12-x86_64-slc6-gcc49-opt/lib/libCling.so)
==344722==    by 0x10B82DCC: clang::ASTReader::GetDecl(unsigned int) (in /cvmfs/atlas.cern.ch/repo/ATLASLocalRootBase/x86_64/root/6.04.12-x86_64-slc6-gcc49-opt/lib/libCling.so)
==344722==    by 0x11036DED: clang::MultiplexExternalSemaSource::GetExternalDecl(unsigned int) (in /cvmfs/atlas.cern.ch/repo/ATLASLocalRootBase/x86_64/root/6.04.12-x86_64-slc6-gcc49-opt/lib/libCling.so)
==344722==    by 0x1114F052: clang::ClassTemplateDecl::LoadLazySpecializations() const (in /cvmfs/atlas.cern.ch/repo/ATLASLocalRootBase/x86_64/root/6.04.12-x86_64-slc6-gcc49-opt/lib/libCling.so)
==344722==    by 0x1114F078: clang::ClassTemplateDecl::getSpecializations() const (in /cvmfs/atlas.cern.ch/repo/ATLASLocalRootBase/x86_64/root/6.04.12-x86_64-slc6-gcc49-opt/lib/libCling.so)
==344722==    by 0x11151209: clang::ClassTemplateDecl::findSpecialization(llvm::ArrayRef<clang::TemplateArgument>, void*&) (in /cvmfs/atlas.cern.ch/repo/ATLASLocalRootBase/x86_64/root/6.04.12-x86_64-slc6-gcc49-opt/lib/libCling.so)
==344722==    by 0x10F55800: clang::Sema::CheckTemplateIdType(clang::TemplateName, clang::SourceLocation, clang::TemplateArgumentListInfo&) (in /cvmfs/atlas.cern.ch/repo/ATLASLocalRootBase/x86_64/root/6.04.12-x86_64-slc6-gcc49-opt/lib/libCling.so)
==344722==    by 0x10FCC354: clang::TreeTransform<(anonymous namespace)::TemplateInstantiator>::TransformTemplateSpecializationType(clang::TypeLocBuilder&, clang::TemplateSpecializationTypeLoc, clang::TemplateName) (in /cvmfs/atlas.cern.ch/repo/ATLASLocalRootBase/x86_64/root/6.04.12-x86_64-slc6-gcc49-opt/lib/libCling.so)
==344722==    by 0x10FB8805: clang::TreeTransform<(anonymous namespace)::TemplateInstantiator>::TransformType(clang::TypeLocBuilder&, clang::TypeLoc) (in /cvmfs/atlas.cern.ch/repo/ATLASLocalRootBase/x86_64/root/6.04.12-x86_64-slc6-gcc49-opt/lib/libCling.so)
==344722==    by 0x10FB8DFC: clang::TreeTransform<(anonymous namespace)::TemplateInstantiator>::TransformType(clang::TypeLocBuilder&, clang::TypeLoc) (in /cvmfs/atlas.cern.ch/repo/ATLASLocalRootBase/x86_64/root/6.04.12-x86_64-slc6-gcc49-opt/lib/libCling.so)
```

Comment: An exception is being thrown presumably. Just run whatever you're running in a debugger and it will break on the exception (assuming you're not catching it) then look at the stack trace.

Comment: What development environment are you running under?

Comment: Use a debug build or browse for 'C++ stackoverflow stack trace' if you have a release build, only

Comment: I am running on Linux. This is all command line code used for scientific computing.

Comment: I am currently trying to use GDB to see if that gives me any more information. I should have said above that this framwork uses python as a UI and then calls c++ libraries and classes to do all the heavy lifting algorithms.

Comment: A nice tool for your issue is 'valgrind' (but ignore the python related output)

Comment: For those with a similar problem, but who are using Visual Studio, you could try right-clicking the function definition and choosing View Call Hierarchy to see all the places where it is called from.

Comment: Fix this first: `Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)`.  After that, you might ensure no C++ exception is bubbling to python.

Comment: Use `catch throw` in gdb to break where the exception is thrown.